# Setup test environment for Strapi project

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, strapi

I am trying to setup unit test for a Strapi project my code looks like below

*test_utils.js*

```js
const Strapi = require("strapi");
const http = require('http');

let instance; // singleton 
jest.setTimeout(10000)

async function setupStrapi() {
  if (!instance) {
    instance = Strapi()
    await instance.load();

    // Run bootstrap function.
    await instance.runBootstrapFunctions();
    // Freeze object.
    await instance.freeze();

    instance.app.use(instance.router.routes()).use(instance.router.allowedMethods());
    instance.server = http.createServer(instance.app.callback());
  }
  return instance;
}

module.exports = { setupStrapi }
```

*controllers.test.js*

```js
const request = require("supertest")
const {setupStrapi, setupUser} = require("../../test_utils")

describe("chat-group controllers", ()=>{
    let strapi
    beforeAll(async ()=>{
        strapi = await setupStrapi()
    })

    test("endpoint tasks", async (done)=>{
        app = strapi

        app.server.listen(app.config.port, app.config.host)
        const resp = await request(app.server).get("/testpublics")
        .expect(200)

        console.log(resp.body)
        done()
    })
})
```

when I run the test, I get 403 error on "/testpublics". Note that "/testpublics" is public api and I can access it from browser.

I think the problem is with `setupStrapi` function, I took the code from `node_modules/strapi/lib/strapi.js` file.

What is the better way to setup unit test for Strapi project. I want to achieve following

- start test with clean database each time
- test public and authenticated api endpoints

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. Go to `./api/name-of-your-api/config/routes.json` and remove the config property for each of the endpoints.

It should be this:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/testpublics",
      "handler": "testpublics.index"
    },
}
```

as opposed to this:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/testpublics",
      "handler": "testpublics.index",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this route to by public by policy, answer from @sama-bala resolves everything.

For Strapi the custom route and controller that is not public (needs JWT token in Request header) must be assigned to role — otherwise even for a valid token controller will throw Forbidden 403 error. The whole process is described in Authenticated request [tutorial on Strapi documentation page](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/auth-request.html#setup). This information is saved in the database only. Usually you do this in the admin panel, not from source code.

Have a look on the following snippet

```js
/**
 * Grants database `permissions` table that role can access an endpoint/controllers
 *
 * @param {int} roleID, 1 Autentihected, 2 Public, etc
 * @param {string} value, in form or dot string eg `"permissions.users-permissions.controllers.auth.changepassword"`
 * @param {boolean} enabled, default true
 * @param {string} policy, default ''
 */
const grantPrivilage = async (
  roleID = 1,
  value,
  enabled = true,
  policy = ""
) => {
  const updateObj = value
    .split(".")
    .reduceRight((obj, next) => ({ [next]: obj }), { enabled, policy });

  return await strapi.plugins[
    "users-permissions"
  ].services.userspermissions.updateRole(roleID, updateObj);
};
```

It allows you to assign route to role programatically by updating the database. In case of your code the solution might look like that

```js
  await grantPrivilage(2, "permissions.application.controllers.testpublics.index"); // 1 is default role for Autheticated user, 2 is Public role.
```

You can add this in `beforeAll` or in `bootstrap.js`, eg

```js
beforeAll(async (done) => {
  user = await userFactory.createUser(strapi);
  await grantPrivilage(1, "permissions.application.controllers.hello.hi");
  done();
});
```

I've tried to explore this topic in [my blog post](https://medium.com/qunabu-interactive/strapi-testing-more-examples-b09b07088353)